# RTSP Media Server Solutions

Tags: android, media, rtsp, multimedia

After carrying out a lot of research I have come to the conclusion that Java and  the Java Media Framework (JMF) is not suitable for developing a streaming server that supports the RTSP protocol on the server side for streaming video and audio. I have read very good things about Live555 media server and the testOnDemandRTSPServer source code for a basis of design. My only worry is that this is written in C++ and I am a predominantly Java programmer. This server is a large portion of my final year project at university so my degree kind of hangs on its successful implementation and I am running out of time. If any one has any experience with implementing a RTSP server that can stream to an android handset or belive they can point me in the right direction to learn how to do it, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry to be more direct and ask questions that can be answered I add:  Has any one succesfully built a basic RTSP server in java? Is Live555 media server a good place to start? Are there any good websites that will walk me through the steps needed to be taken to develop and implement an RTSP media server in any lanaguage? Any answers would be greatly appreicated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The live555 RTSP server is a fully fledged RTSP server that implements most payloads (H.263, H.264, MPEG2, PCM, AMR, AAC, etc. You can read up on the website whether it already supports the media types you want to stream. It also features an RTSP client. With respect to streaming to an android handset: that is the whole point of RTSP: it doesn't matter what type of client you're streaming to, and as for the server side development, there isn't really much dev to do, unless you need to implement an unsupported media type. The code can be quite complex if you're not well versed in c++, but it sounds like your goal is more related to setting up streaming to android as opposed to implementing the RTSP server and client? So check if live555 supports your media types and if it does, I wouldn't bother writing one in JAVA, that can be quite involved. If you do choose to go that route, your best friend is of course the RFC (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2326).

As for the client, I'm not sure if android already has an RTSP library/client. The one other thing you have to consider is which media types are supported by android.

Comment: Hi, Cheers for response its just what I needed to know. My Last question is: As Live555 is open source, does it mean that I can chop and change bits of it as I see fit once I have attained and understood the source without breaking the license. I just think the university would want to be sure that I have made a few of my own changes to prove I fully understand what I am implementing. Thank you.

Comment: Live555 is LGPL so any changes you make to the source must be made available back to the license holder. However you would typically create new classes (e.g. ones that inherit live 555 base) that don't have to be AFAIK. It's a really flexible license though, way more open than GPL for instance.

Comment: @Ralf can you please check my question if you can answer it. I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 2):

My project also has the RTSP server module to be run on Android phone. I think we can build rtsp library as name.so file and can interface with java by using JNI.

Answer (score 1):

This also works for Android!

http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

You can see the article on CodeProject @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

Comment: See the CodeProject article...  Let me know if you have specific questions. There are examples on the project page as well.